# Is there an alternative to std::this_thread::sleep_for that receives std::stop_token besides time duration?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I would like to use **std::this_thread::sleep_for** and **std::this_thread::sleep_until** with **std::stop_token** where the functions return if stop is requested on std::stop_token (ex. jthread destruction is called).
How can I achieve this?

```
std::jthread thread {[](std::stop_token stoken){
    while(!stoken.stop_requested()) {
        std::cout << "Still working..\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s); // use together with stoken
    }
}};
```

Comment: [`std::condition_variable/wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are common uses of condition variables in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476235/what-are-common-uses-of-condition-variables-in-c)

Comment: Your code snippet is somewhat similar to the implementation of `std::condition_varialbe::wait`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my implementation using std::condition_variable as everyone tells that.

```
template<typename _Rep, typename _Period>
void sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& dur, const std::stop_token& stoken)
{
    std::condition_variable_any cv;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul_ {mutex_};
    std::stop_callback stop_wait {stoken, [&cv](){ cv.notify_one(); }};
    cv.wait_for(ul_, dur, [&stoken](){ return stoken.stop_requested(); });
}
```

Comment: This will cause issue mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66309276/why-does-c20-stdcondition-variable-not-support-stdstop-token), so you need to use `std::condition_variable_any`. Anyway this give me direction to my problem thanks.

Comment: So this should be stable when I change std::conditional_variable to std::condition_variable_any?

Comment: Since people may use this as the basis for similar code, I think we should have the `stop_wait` constructed before the `unique_lock` to minimize the critical section (for the case that people use this when the `std::mutex` isn't a local variable). I'll be bold and make the change.

Comment: I opted to not make the change out of paranoia. Would it be correct? That could allow the `std::stop_callback` to do `cv.notify_one()` when the mutex isn't locked. Then the lock locks, the CV misses the notification (?) and then `cv.wait_for` presumably immediately checks the condition and never blocks, so it should be correct, right?

Answer (score 8):

Use a `std::condition_variable`, this covers the 'stop when signalled' part. Then you use [`wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) or [`wait_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until) respectively.

Examples on how to use a condition variable can be found at the links.

Comment: I am not sure if condition_variable is what I want

Comment: @asmbaty To cancel the sleeping of a thread, there are not so many (C++ standard conform) ways I can imagine. To tell it from beginning, to wait for a time _or_ a certain condition is a clean way to do so. Hence, I wonder why you have doubts about condition_variable...

Comment: @asmbaty I'm pretty sure this is what you want. :-)

Comment: @asmbaty But that's what STL has forseen for exactly such use cases as you describe. If you don't like that, you likely will have to write a solution entirely on your own – most likely relying on OS-specific functionality to avoid busy-waits (please do so!).

Comment: std::condition_variable_any::wait_for has an overload since C++20 that receives std::stop_token as an argument.